# Union query on same table multiple time

Tags: sql, t-sql

```sql
Select c.id
from Customer c
     inner join Orders o on (o.cid=c.id)
     where c.companyid=?
union 
     Select c.id
     Customer c
     inner join RecentOrder ro on (ro.cid=c.cid)
     where c.companyid=?
```

How can be performance of the query improved? My customer table has 50k data for one "companyid" and so order and RecentOrder table has also huge data. How can I improve the query performance?

Comment: Performance isn't even the issue right now; that isn't a valid query.

Comment: The UNION needs one SELECT before, and one SELECT after.

Comment: And `ORDER` is a reserved word in SQL, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words. Needs to be delimited as `"ORDER"`. SQL Server also accepts `[ORDER]`.

Comment: instead of union se union all as union has an impact on performance. Union tries to filter out distinct records out of the result.

Comment: @EpicChen yes its for both

Comment: For performance help, you need to give us the index definitions, and share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: @Charlieface you want the execution plan in xml format right?

Comment: Yes, but it's probably going to be too big to add here, which is why I suggested you share it via PasteThePlan. Please also [edit] your post and add index definitions

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `or`:

```
select c.id 
from Customer c 
where exists (select 1
              from Order o
              where o.cid = c.id
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from RecentOrder o
              where o.cid = c.id and c.companyid = ?
             );
```

For the subqueries, you want indexes on `Orders(cid)` and `RecentOrders(cid)`.

Comment: Execution time using this query is much more higher than the posted one.

Comment: @Techie321 . . . Do you have the recommended indexes?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use union all if you are sure of these queries will return identical records.  It will have a improvement on performance as you have higher number of records. Union all has a performance hit as it is selecting unique records in participants.

Your query has a syntax error which i have corrected in this answer. If ou want to filter records of the union go for a derived table after getting the records in union all query.

```
      Select 
        c.id
      from Customer c
       inner join Order o 
            on o.cid=c.id
       where c.companyid=''

       union  all

       Select 
        c.id
      from Customer c
        inner join RecentOrder ro 
          on ro.cid=c.cid
         where c.companyid=''
```

Comment: what's the difference, I didn't get it

Comment: Union and Union all?  Union tries to filter distinct records which will add additional performance hit to the query as you have 50K + records.

Comment: There are some other tips to increase performance as creating indexes on filter columns and using no lock or including indexes. it depends on your requirements. If you can give me the table with data I can provide you a better explanation,  Here  I added a tip to use UNION or UNION ALL. @Techie321

Comment: used union and union all still has negligible impact on query performance

Comment: Can you add some data and table scripts.  So I can try. 
Try using non-clustered index on where condition, If it is the primary key this is not required. I need to see the tables and sample data. @Techie321

Comment: @Techie321 Can you include the query plan / Actual query plan when executing the query ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a non-clustered Index to `[Customer]` table, it will be improved by seeking and reducing the field lookup. However, it can not avoid scanning on `[Order]` and `[RecentOrder]`. If you have set the relations between those tables, the sql optimizer may work fine.

```sql
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Companyid_Customerid] ON [dbo].[Customer]
    (
        [companyid] ASC
    )
    INCLUDE ([id])
    GO
```

It is a sample code as mssql.

Comment: There has already been created index as suggested in execution plan in sql management studio

Comment: Could you provide the screenshot of the actual execution plan?